# Where to initialize Django session variables?

Tags: python, django, session

In my Django project I am building a shopping cart system.  I want to store the shopping cart data in a session variable, but I don't know where to initialize it.

I have tried doing something like this:

```
if 'cart' not in request.session:
    request.session['cart'] = {}
```

in a custom context processor, but the context processor does not seem to modify the session data.  Where else would I put an initialization like this?  I don't want to have to put it in every place where I get values from the cart.

Comment: The context processor will trigger only for templates rendered with a RequestContext. Are you sure you are passing a RequestContext instead of a simple dict or Context object? This works for me.

Comment: This confused me, because yes, I made sure that I am passing a RequestContext.  In fact, other code in the context processor was running, but the initialization code was not.  Maybe I missed something else.  Regardless, the other two solutions are working, so I'll use one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in middleware (underneath the session middleware, obviously) will make certain that it's always set.

Comment: this is really helpful, obviously.

Answer (score 5):

You could put it in a piece of [custom request middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/http/middleware/#process-request), but to be honest, I think that would be overkill here. It's probably easier to just initialize the cart when you need it in your view function. Note that you can use `request.session.get` to automatically grab a default value if the value doesn't already exist. Something like:

```
def my_view(request):
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    # Do stuff with cart
    request.session['cart'] = cart
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to test if cart is in the request.session. Why not do something like this:

```
cart_value = request.session.get('cart',{})
```

Basically what that will do is return the value at 'cart' in session and if there are no values in the cart then return the empty dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work **as is** with a context_processor, assuming your views are always using RequestContext.

I'm doing exactly the same thing for my cart, based on Satchmo of a few years back.
I have a context_processor where I find the Cart from the session and pass it to the template.
A lot of other session modification is done there too...

So.. your code should work as is. Is it executing at all? Is it installed?